# What is a Windows text editor that will make it easy for me to have four text files open onscreen at once?

Tags: windows-7, windows, software-rec, text-editors

When brainstorming / planning I like to have four text files open onscreen at once: One for notes/stream of consciousness, one for action items to follow up on, one for a rough outline, etc.... What I'm looking for is an easy way to create / save four text files in this manner in Windows.

Most importantly, I need the lines to wrap based on the width of the actual window itself. Not based on a ruler or document size (a la [Word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word) or [WordPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad)) and not wrapping "manually only" (like Windows' built in [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) application.) Also, I need the windows to have no, or at least, little, fluff at the top of each document (menubars, ribbons, etc.)

On my Mac, I've found that the built-in [TextEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit) application is almost perfect for this. There's no header or ribbon taking up space for each document, and lines wrap when they hit the end of the window. I haven't had any luck finding a Windows application that works the same way.

Comment: If you don't mind having four Notepad instances open, use menu: Format, word-wrap.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I didn't even know Notepad had that option... that's pretty much exactly what I was looking for... I'd give you credit for answering the question if it was submitted as an answer!

Comment: Answer submitted as requested (Oh heck, I'm so greedy.)

Comment: which editor doesn't have the word-wrap ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind having four Notepad instances open, use menu: `Format, word-wrap.`

Answer (score 3):

Both [Emacs](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html) and [Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php) can do this. But beware that the learning curve of both are a bit steep (totally worth it IMO).

This *[Emacs Crib Sheet](http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/~robishaw/comp/emacs.crib.html)* or *[The Vim commands cheat sheet](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html)* should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

[Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/) (which are a bunch of scripts that make [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) much simpler for regular users) has the word wrapping features you want - it can wrap on the border of that particular pane, and has very little fluff for split windows.

Here's a screenshot of [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) on my computer, which is similar enough. It shows the wrapping of text according to that window's borders:

[image]

Comment: You can go on and type:
    <ESC>:set go=-T<ENTER>
to hide Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) can do that. Just enable word wrap with Strg+W.

Costs money but it is well worth it.

Comment: Any editor can do that because word-wrapping is such a very basic function. For whoever don't know German: Strg is Ctrl on your keyboard